# Why it is showing false when I insert 3 or more than 3 characters after s?

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

class RegexEx
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name=new String();
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter Name : ");
        name=s.next();
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[s][a-zA-Z]",name));
        if(Pattern.matches("[s][a-zA-Z]",name))
        {
            System.out.println("\nValid Name");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nInValid Name");
        }
    }
}
```

cmd:

```
C:\Users\student\Desktop>javac RegexEx.java

C:\Users\student\Desktop>java RegexEx


Enter Name : s
false

InValid Name

C:\Users\student\Desktop>java RegexEx


Enter Name : sa
true

Valid Name

C:\Users\student\Desktop>java RegexEx


Enter Name : sam
false

InValid Name

C:\Users\student\Desktop>
```

Comment: Because of the pattern - `"[s][a-zA-Z]"` that only allows matching 2 chars. If you want more, use either `"[s][a-zA-Z]+"` or `"[s][a-zA-Z].*"`. What are your requirements?

Comment: so, what to do so that it can match as much required characters

Comment: I would recommend you to learn regex in detail.

Comment: You still have not explained what characters are required.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments. Your regular expression `[s][a-zA-Z]` is wrong, given your expectations. It matches **2 character** long strings that start with `s` followed by a single upper or lower case letter.

As you did not specify any explicit expectations it's hard to provide the correct expression for your needs. Probably you want to match arbitrary long strings that start with `s` and are at least 2 characters long?! This could be achieved by this expression:

```
[s][a-zA-Z]+
```

I always use [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/) to develop/debug more complex regular expressions. It does not directly support Java regular expressions but the syntax is very similar across languages. Although your expression is not "too" complex the evaluation section might help you to understand how the expressions work.